# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, lejos-nxj

I am writing a small java code to generate random values:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    public class Rann {
       static Random rand;
       public static void main(String args[]){
           int i;
           for(i=0;i<15;i++)
               System.out.println(rand.nextInt(7));
       }
    }
```

This gives an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Rann.main(Rann.java:7)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. And is this the preferred way to generate random values in LeJOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you haven't initialized your random object

```
static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

For best way to generate random numbers you can take a look at [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/java-generating-random-number-in-a-range)

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate the Random object

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this. You forgot to tell it to make a new Random-Class object.

```
package foso;
import java.util.Random;
public class FoSo {
   static Random rand = new Random();
   public static void main(String args[]){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<15;i++)
           System.out.println(rand.nextInt(7));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Who will initialize your `rand`?

```
   static Random rand = new Random();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize your `rand`variable before using it.